# How can I update a date field format in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like below

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe7718733e"),
    "project_name" : "p1",
    "expected" : "19-Sep-2019",
    "actual" : "19-Sep-2019"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe77187340"),
    "project_name" : "p2",
    "expected" : "20-Sep-2019",
    "actual" : "20-Sep-2019"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe77187340"),
    "project_name" : "p2",
    "actual" : "20-Sep-2019"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe77187340"),
    "project_name" : "p2",
    "expected" : "",
    "actual" : "20-Sep-2019"
}
```

I need to update the 2 fields expected and actual in the this format YYYY-MM-DD.
How can I write an update Query for this?

Comment: Do you wanted to update to all docs in DB ? what is your mongo version ?

Comment: yes. version is 4.0.4

Comment: If you could upgrade to 4.2 you might be able to take advantage of new update that supports aggregation pipelines else you need to create a whole new collection to do this(One call Db but you need to drop existing collection if newly created has good data) or do reads by aggregation & do writes for all docs(two calls)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB `V4.0` & since this is one-time operation, You can try this :

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            expected: {
                $cond: [
                    {
                        $and: [
                            {
                                $ne: [
                                    "$expected",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $ne: [
                                    {
                                        $type: "$expected"
                                    },
                                    "missing"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        $dateToString: {
                            format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                            date: {
                                $dateFromString: {
                                    dateString: "$expected"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    ""
                ]
            },
            actual: {
                $cond: [
                    {
                        $and: [
                            {
                                $ne: [
                                    "$actual",
                                    ""
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $ne: [
                                    {
                                        $type: "$actual"
                                    },
                                    "missing"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        $dateToString: {
                            format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                            date: {
                                $dateFromString: {
                                    dateString: "$actual"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    }, { $out: "collection_new" }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LKQN80MUHxS)

**Note :** You need to careful with [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) the input name in this stage should not match with any existing collection name, if it does it would drop the collection & re-create it with result of aggregation, if you need to do this process over time use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) instead of `$out`. Also once you feel you've correct data in `collection_new` - you can drop existing `collection` & rename new collection to old name.

Comment: How can I give a condition for this add field?. Like for some cases I don't have expected field. or its an empty string.I updated my question

Comment: $addFields: {                 
                actual:{   
                 $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$actual", "" ] }, 
                          then: "",
                          else:  {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d" ,date: {  $dateFromString: {
                            dateString: "$actual"
                        }
                    }
                }
            } } }               
        }

Comment: I added a condition like this. but it is updating as null

Comment: @user1187 : Is that updating as `null` if `actual` doesn't exists ?

Comment: yes as per my condition. I wont it to be empty string

Comment: @user1187 : Do you mean to say if you don't have `actual` field at all then you need to have empty or don't want `actual` field as original doesn't has it ?

Comment: yes. If the field not empty then only I need to format

Comment: @user1187 : No I mean if field it self is not there then ? for `"_id" : ObjectId("5ceb7e71636566fe77187340")` what should be the o/p look like ?

Comment: it won't really effect me if if we give  "expected" : "" , but as per my condition it shows  "expected" : null,

Comment: can't we do a condition expression  without else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207236/discussion-between-user1187-and-whoami).

Answer (score 1):

You can run this script in mongo shell.

```
db.collectionName.find({}).forEach( function(myDoc) { 
    print(myDoc._id);

    var expected = "20-Sep-2019";
    expected = expected.split("-");
    expected = expected[2]+"-"+expected[1]+"-"+expected[0];
    print(expected);


    var actual = "15-Sep-2019";
    actual = actual.split("-");
    actual = actual[2]+"-"+actual[1]+"-"+actual[0];
    print(actual);

    db.collectionName.update({_id : myDoc._id, },{$set : {expected : expected, actual : actual}});
});
```

But my suggestion is that you should store date in ISODate format so later on you can do calculation very easily and you can query with date for greater than or less than correctly.